# Why can't I edit certain questions?

Tags: support, editing

I don't have edit privileges yet, but I can submit edits for review which I have done a few times. But certain questions don't show me the edit option, such as [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/704/arab-christians-and-the-crusades). I had just corrected the title of another recent question by this user and was going to do the same here. It's not closed and has no accepted answer, so what's different about this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has another edit already pending.

You won't be able to edit until it's approved or declined.